# Express & Passport with multiple subdomains

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm merging two little apps into one, that is supposed to be accessed via two subdomains. To do so I'm using the module "express-subdomain". I'm trying to use Passport so when a user logs in in the first app, he is logged in in both apps. However using `req.isAuthenticated()` I can indeed login in the "first" app, but then I'm not in the "second" one.

I'm searching for any solution to have a passport authentification in the first subdomain and being logged in in the second one, including keeping two disctinct apps if needed.

Assuming that passport is correctly configured for a local strategy, as well as the routers and the rest of the app. Here is what it looks like :

**app.js**

```
// <- requires etc

var passport = require('./configurePassport.js')(require('passport'));

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'bestSecretEver',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
// and others

var firstRouter = express.Router();
firstRouter.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/first/public'));
firstRouter.use(favicon(__dirname + '/first/public/favicon.ico'));

// <- setting first router's GET, POST etc

app.use(subdomain('sub1', firstRouter)); // for sub1.example.com

var secondRouter = express.Router();
secondRouter.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/second/public'));
secondRouter.use(favicon(__dirname + '/second/public/favicon.ico'));

// <- setting second router's GET, POST etc

app.use(subdomain('sub2', secondRouter)); // for sub2.example.com
```

Any idea ?

Comment: How are you saving your authentication token?

Comment: Sorry i'm going to precise it. I'm editing it right away. (I'm using express session i suppose ?)

Comment: Look into where you're saving your cookies for authentication purposes. Make sure you have it saved to the root domain. ie: `*.example.com` and not `sub1.example.com`

Comment: That's it ! I changed the expressSession configuration adding a `cookie: {domain:'.example.com'}` (example.com being my domain) and now that works fine. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Mark the answer below as completed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into where you're saving your cookies for authentication purposes. Make sure you have it saved to the root domain. ie: `*.example.com` and not `sub1.example.com`